# Bootstrap dropdown menu not working within _Layout.cshtml Shared in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am attempting to implement a dropdown menu in my shared _Layout and am unfortunately not successful.

Do you guys know what the issue is here:

```
    <nav>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn" data-toggle="dropdown"> This that </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

When I do display: block on my ul I can see the drop down, however in the above case when I click the button nothing drops down.

Comment: Are the Bootstrap resources loaded?

Comment: bootstrap 2.3.2 or 3.0.0?

Comment: yes resources are loaded that is why I display:block shows drop down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my workaround in case someone was still looking for.

```
   .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {display: block;}

   .nav-tabs .dropdown-menu, .nav-pills .dropdown-menu, .navbar .dropdown-menu
     {margin-top: 0;}
```

Comment: this is the ever best answer! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

this may be useless now. but i wanted to share what the actual problem was.

I faced the same problem. 
the problem is importing both the normal and minified versions of bootstrap css files.

//wrong way

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/vendor/bootstrap.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/vendor/bootstrap-theme.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" />
 <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/vendor/bootstrap.css")" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/vendor/bootstrap-theme.css")" rel="stylesheet" />
```

//right way

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/vendor/bootstrap.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/vendor/bootstrap-theme.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on ASP.NET MVC 5 and encountered the same problem. My solution was to include jquery.min.js and bootstrap.min.js scripts within the < head > section of the _Layout.cshtml.

Comment: But once you fill up a Razor code in one of the links, this method will not work. Apparently the problem only occurs when all of the links in the menu are pure html.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a dropdown menu button. It's work for me. You can just modified it.

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should help.

```
<li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                            Profile
                            <span class="caret"></span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("My Profile", "Add", "Storage")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Log Out", "LogOut", "Login")</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
```